# Where can I get a replacement screen for a Dell M1530?

Tags: laptop, display

I tragically dropped my m1530, busted up the screen real bad.

It had the glossy WXGA+ screen - does anyone know where i can get a replacement?

I'm in Australia.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have valid warranty, just call DELL support.

If you don't have, try DELL support and ask them, how much cost is replacement part, but it's expensive.

Best way if you don't have warranty is look to eBay and do change yourself.

Comment: i did ask dell - and it was damn expensive.

Ebay has them going for $300 USD.

I think I'm going to have to stick with the external monitor setup.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is to contact support at [www.dell.com.au](http://www.dell.com.au).  Is there some reason they can't help you?

Comment: Sorry my bad - i should have mentioned, my warranty has expired.

Answer (score -1):

[screencountry.com](http://screencountry.com) has your replacement screen for $147.  This Canadian vendor has been the best source for LCD replacements for years.  Highly recommended.